# Звонок из Android приложения с последующим нажатием кнопок

Tags: android

Проблема такая: 
Звоню из андроид-приложения, как обычно

`Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:3211234"));
startActivity(call);`

На звонок отвечает офисная АТС-робот, которая говорит что надо нажимать кнопки (типа "Вы дозвонились в Райвоенкомат. Если хотите служить в армии-нажмите звёздочку, если не хотите служить в армии-нажмите решётку. ")

Как мне нажать звездочку из моего приложения?

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте вот так

```
Intent call = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, 
Uri.parse("tel:3211234"+PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE+"#"));
//или вместо PhoneNumberUtils.PAUSE - PhoneNumberUtils.WAIT
```

Comment: Прошу прощения если глупость спрошу, а можно как-нибудь из приложения эмулировать нажатия кнопок или касание экрана? 
Ну, то есть когда будет висеть экран звонилки, вызвать в приложении функцию типа PressKey("1") или TouchScreen(120, 200) ?

Comment: @Dmbor можно, но только из под рута.

Comment: В Рут вроде перевел и попробовал использовать Instrumentation 
 (типа                 instrumentation.sendPointerSync(MotionEvent.obtain(
                        android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN,x, y, 0));
Но желаемого эффекта не достиг - требует установить Permission 
"Injecting to another application requires INJECT_EVENTS permission"
В манифест вроде соответствующую строчку добавил, но нажатия так и не эмулируются...